# Elastic search multiple terms in a dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mapping like:

```
 "profile": {
        "properties": {               
            "educations": {
                "properties": {
                    "university": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "graduation_year": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
   }
```

which obviously holds the educations history of people. Each person can have multiple educations. What I want to do is search for people who graduated from "SFU" in "2012". To do that I am using filtered search:

```
"filtered": {
     "filter": {
        "and": [
           {
              "term": {
                 "educations.university": "SFU"
              }
           },
           {
              "term": {
                 "educations.graduation_year": "2012"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
```

But what this query does is to find the documents who have "SFU" and "2012" in their education, so this document would match, which is wrong:

```
educations[0] = {"university": "SFU", "graduation_year": 2000}
educations[1] = {"university": "UBC", "graduation_year": 2012}
```

Is there anyway I could filter both terms on each education?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define nested type for `educations` and use nested filter to filter it, or Elasticsearch will internally flattens inner objects into a single object, and return the wrong results.
You can refer here for detail explainations and samples:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/
http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/